# Prove that $\sin x<x$, if $x>0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove that $\sin x<x$, if $x>0$.

May it seems a silly question, but I don't know how to prove it analytically (i.e., without comparing graph of $\sin x$ and $x$) and without more advanced topics, e.g. Taylor series, or even derivation.

Please help me how can I prove it for a middle-school student, using definition of $\sin x$ or maybe some trigonometric identities.

Thank you.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: Not duplicate; I know all the methods written in the link you mentioned, but I am trying to prove it geometrically for a pre-high-school.

Comment: Then middle-school methods should be added as another answer on that question. It would be better to have all the proofs in one place.

Comment: You can find this inequality also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390899/sinx-inequality It is also proved in some answers on questions about limits, such as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117548/i-want-to-prove-the-following-limit-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-sin-xx2 (And you could look also at some other posts listed on the right among related questions.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the unit circle. $\alpha$ is the length of the arc, while $\sin(\alpha)$ is the length of the orthogonal projection on the $x$-axis. For obvious reasons - a middle school student will believe you - the arc is longer.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Add to it that one can assume $x<\pi/2$, because for $x\ge\pi/2$ the inequality is obvious.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in a diagram, taken from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/75135/50776. (That question also includes many geometric proofs of $\sin x<x<\tan x$, since it is a lemma for $\sin x/x\to1$.)

Comment: I would believe that already for $x>1$ the inequality is obvious.

Comment: Yes of course, but that geometric argument works fine for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and one should point that out.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro How did you draw that picture?

Comment: @pushpen.paul Ask [J.M.](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/75135/2), who edited in the diagram from the linked question.